Importing KML into MySQL
I have this KML file to insert in a MySQL table:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<kml
xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Document id="root_doc">
<Schema name="secc_cpv_e_20111101_01_r_ine" id="secc_cpv_e_20111101_01_r_ine">
<SimpleField name="Name" type="string"></SimpleField>
</Schema>
<Folder>
<name>secc_cpv_e_20111101_01_r_ine</name>
<Placemark>
<name>5200101001</name>
<Style>
<LineStyle>
<color>ff0000ff</color>
</LineStyle>
<PolyStyle>
<fill>0</fill>
</PolyStyle>
</Style>
<MultiGeometry>
<Polygon>
<outerBoundaryIs>
<LinearRing>
<coordinates>-2.93698273596522,35.2979346176443,0 -2.93697084790041,35.2979326186938,0 -2.93695877204193,35.297933090301,0 -2.93694953435202,35.2979385903615,0 -2.93694137509274,35.2979447898008,0 -2.93692885164904,35.297946595687,0 -2.93691871628878,35.2979409773216,0 -2.93691413103252,35.2979323321398,0 -2.93690399979109,35.2979270789636,0 -2.93689431492369,35.2979220514443,0 -2.93688289797324,35.2979224151838,0 -2.93687516563971,35.2979298005764,0 </coordinates>
</LinearRing>
</outerBoundaryIs>
</Polygon>
</MultiGeometry>
</Placemark>
</Folder>
</Document>
</kml>

When i launch the PHP to insert the KML into MySQL, only takes the beginning of coordinates, does not catch all data; records NULL in coordinates field:
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML(file_get_contents('demo.kml'));
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('Folder') as $warehouse)
{
    $warehouseName = $warehouse->getElementsByTagName('name')[0]->nodeValue;
    foreach ($warehouse->getElementsByTagName('Placemark') as $placemark)
    {
        $polygons = $placemark->getElementsByTagName('Polygon');
        if ($polygons->length > 0)
        {
            $coordinates = $polygons[0]->getElementsByTagName('coordinates');
            if ($coordinates->length > 0)
            {
                $zoneName = $placemark->getElementsByTagName('name')[0]->nodeValue;
               // $zoneDesc = $placemark->getElementsByTagName('description')[0]->nodeValue;
                $coordinates = explode("\n", $coordinates[0]->nodeValue);
                $coordinatesMysql = array();
                
                foreach ($coordinates as $coordinate)
                {
                    $coordinate = trim($coordinate);
                    if (!empty($coordinate))
                    {
                        list($lon, $lat, $elevation) = explode(",", trim($coordinate));
                        $coordinatesMysql[] = "$lat $lon";
                    }
                }

                echo 'insert into demozonas (name,polygon) values '
                    ."('$zoneName',ST_PolygonFromText('Polygon(("
                    .implode(', ', $coordinatesMysql)
                    ."))'));\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
?>

The result of insert command is:
insert into demozonas (name,polygon) values ('5200101001',ST_PolygonFromText('Polygon((35.2979346176443 -2.93698273596522))'));`

I tried with another KMLs examples and works, but i can't see where is the error in my KML file, Can anyoner help me please?

You are exploding the value of the coordinates element at \n, line breaks - but your given example file doesn't look like it actually contained any in the first place?

Hi @CBroe, exploding is the trouble? What i mean is that when php launch insert, it seems like truncate, only takes from  lat and long, but only the first. The rest of lats and long in the element does not appears in insert statement

What i mean is that only appears the first 35.2979346176443 -2.93698273596522 but the rest not. -2.93698273596522,35.2979346176443,0 -2.93697084790041,35.2979326186938,0 -2.93695877204193,35.297933090301,0 -2.93694953435202,35.2979385903615,0 -2.93694137509274,35.2979447898008,0 -2.93692885164904,35.297946595687,0 -2.93691871628878,35.2979409773216,0 -2.93691413103252,35.2979323321398,0 -2.93690399979109,35.2979270789636,0 -2.93689431492369,35.2979220514443,0 -2.93688289797324,35.2979224151838,0 -2.93687516563971,35.2979298005764,0

"exploding is the trouble?" - if the input value doesn't contain any line breaks, then of course it is. $coordinates = explode("\n", $coordinates[0]->nodeValue); will get you an array with only one single entry, and that entry is the whole content of the coordinates element.

Ok, the input value of coordinates has all data in one line. I've tried to remove exploding but something i'm making bad because php fails.

"Remove exploding" doesn't make any sense here to begin with. You still need to separate these pieces of information, to be able to process them all individually. Instead of a line break, it looks like the separator between the triples of data here is simply a space character, so explode on that instead.

I've maid this change: $coordinates = explode(" ", $coordinates[0]->nodeValue); and now just appears all values minus the 0 that is in all groups of values

What is "now just appears" supposed to mean? The 0 values appear to be the elevation, which your code was supposed to ignore in the first place by the looks of it.

Sorry, it's ok, is the elevation. I'm new with all of this, sorry again. At last, how must i change the insert statement, i remove echo and other characters but does not works. The echo is: echo 'insert into demozonas (name,polygon) values '
."('$zoneName',ST_PolygonFromText('Polygon(("
.implode(', ', $coordinatesMysql)
."))'));";

I don't know what statement syntax you actually need there. The original code should have resulted in something like ST_PolygonFromText('Polygon((lat1 lon1,lat2 lon2,...))'), as far as I can tell.

The coordinates value seems to be separated by spaces not line feeds. Xpath can simplify the code and it can normalize the coordinates value.
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML(getKMLString());
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
// register prefix for namespace
$xpath->registerNamespace('kml', 'http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2');

$records = [];
// iterate placemarks with polygon descendants
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//kml:Folder/kml:Placemark[count(.//kml:Polygon) > 0]') as $placemark) {
    // fetch the first polygon inside $placemark
    foreach ($xpath->evaluate('(//kml:Polygon)[1]', $placemark) as $polygon) {
        // fetch coordinates as string with all whitespaces normalized to single space characters
        $coordinates = parseCoordinates($xpath->evaluate('normalize-space(.//kml:coordinates)', $polygon));
        $records[] = [
            // fetch $placemakr name as string
            'name' => trim($xpath->evaluate('string(kml:name)', $placemark)),
            // compile $coordinates array to Polygon((...))
            'polygon' => coordinatesToPolygon($coordinates),
            'coordinates' => $coordinates,
        ];
        
    }
    
}
var_dump($records);

// parse coordinates into a nested array
function parseCoordinates(string $coordinates) {
    return array_map(
        function($coordinate) {
            [$latitude, $longitude] = explode(',', $coordinate);
            return [$latitude, $longitude];
        },
        explode(' ', $coordinates)
    );
}

function coordinatesToPolygon(array $coordinates) {
    return 'Polygon(('.implode(
        ', ', array_map(fn ($coordinate) => implode(' ', $coordinate), $coordinates)
    ).'))';
}

function getKMLString() {
    return <<<'XML'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<kml
xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Document id="root_doc">
<Schema name="secc_cpv_e_20111101_01_r_ine" id="secc_cpv_e_20111101_01_r_ine">
<SimpleField name="Name" type="string"></SimpleField>
</Schema>
<Folder>
<name>secc_cpv_e_20111101_01_r_ine</name>
<Placemark>
<name>5200101001</name>
<Style>
<LineStyle>
<color>ff0000ff</color>
</LineStyle>
<PolyStyle>
<fill>0</fill>
</PolyStyle>
</Style>
<MultiGeometry>
<Polygon>
<outerBoundaryIs>
<LinearRing>
<coordinates>-2.93698273596522,35.2979346176443,0 -2.93697084790041,35.2979326186938,0 -2.93695877204193,35.297933090301,0 -2.93694953435202,35.2979385903615,0 -2.93694137509274,35.2979447898008,0 -2.93692885164904,35.297946595687,0 -2.93691871628878,35.2979409773216,0 -2.93691413103252,35.2979323321398,0 -2.93690399979109,35.2979270789636,0 -2.93689431492369,35.2979220514443,0 -2.93688289797324,35.2979224151838,0 -2.93687516563971,35.2979298005764,0 </coordinates>
</LinearRing>
</outerBoundaryIs>
</Polygon>
</MultiGeometry>
</Placemark>
</Folder>
</Document>
</kml>
XML;
}

Output:
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "5200101001"
    ["polygon"]=>
    string(439) "Polygon((-2.93698273596522 35.2979346176443, -2.93697084790041 35.2979326186938, -2.93695877204193 35.297933090301, -2.93694953435202 35.2979385903615, -2.93694137509274 35.2979447898008, -2.93692885164904 35.297946595687, -2.93691871628878 35.2979409773216, -2.93691413103252 35.2979323321398, -2.93690399979109 35.2979270789636, -2.93689431492369 35.2979220514443, -2.93688289797324 35.2979224151838, -2.93687516563971 35.2979298005764))"
    ["coordinates"]=>
    array(12) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(17) "-2.93698273596522"
        [1]=>
        string(16) "35.2979346176443"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(17) "-2.93697084790041"
        [1]=>
        string(16) "35.2979326186938"
      }
      [2]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(17) "-2.93695877204193"
        [1]=>
        string(15) "35.297933090301"
      }
      [3]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(17) "-2.93694953435202"
        [1]=>
        string(16) "35.2979385903615"
      }
      [4]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(17) "-2.93694137509274"
        [1]=>
        string(16) "35.2979447898008"
      }
      [5]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(17) "-2.93692885164904"
        [1]=>
        string(15) "35.297946595687"
      }
      [6]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(17) "-2.93691871628878"
        [1]=>
        string(16) "35.2979409773216"
      }
      [7]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(17) "-2.93691413103252"
        [1]=>
        string(16) "35.2979323321398"
      }
      [8]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(17) "-2.93690399979109"
        [1]=>
        string(16) "35.2979270789636"
      }
      [9]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(17) "-2.93689431492369"
        [1]=>
        string(16) "35.2979220514443"
      }
      [10]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(17) "-2.93688289797324"
        [1]=>
        string(16) "35.2979224151838"
      }
      [11]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(17) "-2.93687516563971"
        [1]=>
        string(16) "35.2979298005764"
      }
    }
  }
}

